# "Uninstalling pip-19.0.1:" hangs

Tags: pip

I tried to do `pip install --upgrade pip` in my Mac, but it hanged at `Uninstalling pip-19.0.1:`.

Could anyone tell me what I should do?

```
Ties-MBP:10studio-4 chengtie$ pip install --upgrade pip
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/0c/d01aa759fdc501a58f431eb594a17495f15b88da142ce14b5845662c13f3/pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 1.1MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-19.0.1:
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it with an administrator account. Try "sudo pip install --upgrade pip".